# Replace backup location in SQL jobs

Tags: sql-server, powershell

We are trying to replace a backup location in a SQL Backup Jobs step (running power shell through several  servers) 
Below is a PS script i would like to use it:

```
# $Server is a file with SERVERNAME names 
$Jobs = Get-SQLAgentJob -ServerInstance 
$Servers Foreach ($job in $Jobs.Where{$_.Name -like 'DatabaseBackup' -and $_.isenabled -eq $true}) { 
    foreach ($Step in $Job.jobsteps.Where{$_.Name -like 'DatabaseBackup'}) { 
        $Step.Command = $Step.Command.Replace("Directory = N'C:\Backup\oldname1\oldname2\SERVERNAME'", "Directory = N'C:\Backup2\newname1\newname2\SERVERNAME'")
        $Step.Alter() 
        } 
}
```

Comment: My question is how to replace 
\Backup\oldname1\oldname2
 with \Backup2\newname1\newname2.

Thank you.

Comment: _Please edit the question, do not add details as comment._ So what exactly is the problem? What happens when you run the script? Is there an error message? Nothing happens? Path changes in unexpected way?

Comment: Errr... just edit your code? I guess I don't understand what you're asking. Can you [edit] your question and clarify?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this should work. The only potential problems I see are the following:

1. named SQL instances: The $servers variable will need to have the servername\instancename format if not using the default instance name
2. Job and step names: If your job names and job step names are not exactly databasebackup, case excluded, then the -like operator combined with the exact string will not find a match. If the names contain the databasebackup string, you will be safer to use **-match "databasebackup"** or -like with asterisks on both sides of the string.

Otherwise, this code should just work provided there are not network connectivity or permissions issues.